# Graphs from several margins in one marginsplot in Stata

Tags: plot, stata, margins

I would like to draw margins resulting from the `margins` command in one marginsplot, but from different `margins` estimations. Important restriction: These coefficients are within the same min and max and therefore comparable. How do I do that?

Here is a code example:

```
webuse nhanes2, clear

tnbreg psu weight hdresult iron, iterate(5) // I am using this regression type so I stick with it here
```

I know that I can put all margins response graphs in one plot

```
margins, dydx(*)
marginsplot, horizontal xline(0) yscale(reverse) recast(scatter)
```

But in fact I am running three `margins` command for each of the regressors separately, because I want to compare the effects if that regressor would vary. The code hence is

```
foreach var in weight hdresult iron {
  * Procedure to get the numbers for margins right
  quietly summarize `var '
  local max = r(max)
  local step = round(r(max)/6)

  quietly margins, at(`cvar'=(1(`step')`max'))
  marginsplot, title("") ytitle("")
}
```

This gives me three separate files. But I want all the lines in one single figure, in different colors, of course.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @RobertoFerrer's suggestion to use `combomarginsplot` I am now tricking that package (thanks to Nicholas Winter):

```
webuse nhanes2, clear

* Run regressions
foreach var in weight hdresult iron {
  * Trick: always regress on the same variable
  gen testvar = `var'

  * Any regression where testvar enters first - the identical variable will be omitted
  tnbreg psu ///
     testvar weight hdresult iron, iterate(5)

  * Procedure to get the numbers for margins right
  quietly summarize testvar
  local max = r(max)
  local step = round(r(max)/6)

  * Margins post estimation
  quietly margins, at(testvar=(1(`step')`max')) saving(margins_`var', replace)

  * Drop testvar so that it can be reassigned within the loop
  drop testvar
}

* Combine the margins graph information
combomarginsplot margins_weight margins_hdresult margins_iron, labels("Weight" "HDrestul" "Iron")
```

Of course, it only makes sense to compare coefficients of variables that are all within the same range. This restriction wasn't part of my original answer - sorry for that.

Answer (score 6):

Using `combomarginsplot` (and from the help file):

```
sysuse auto, clear

oprobit rep78 i.foreign mpg price weight
margins foreign, at(mpg=(10(5)50)) predict(outcome(3)) saving(file1, replace)

oprobit rep78 i.foreign mpg
margins foreign, at(mpg=(10(5)50)) predict(outcome(3)) saving(file2, replace)

oprobit rep78 i.foreign mpg gear
margins foreign, at(mpg=(10(5)50)) predict(outcome(3)) saving(file3, replace)

combomarginsplot file1 file2 file3, ///
    labels("Full model" "Restricted model" "Gear Model") noci
```

`combomarginsplot` is a user-written command by Nicholas Winter. You can install it running

```
ssc install combomarginsplot
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem has been solved with `combomargins`. Unfortunately, `combomargins` doesn't work with StataMP17.

For anyone who's interested in displaying multiple `margins` results within one marginsplot, and without the help of `combomargins`, here's a solution inspired by [www.statalist.org](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1311696-overlaying-two-marginsplot).

```
    sysuse auto, clear

    reg price i.foreign weight
    margins, dydx(weight) predict(outcome(3)) post
    est store m1

    reg price rep78 i.foreign mpg
    margins, dydx(rep78) predict(outcome(3)) post
    est store m2

    coefplot m1 m2
```

The key is to use `margins` option `post` to:

> post margins and their VCE as estimation results

Then, you can use `coefplots` to overlay multiple marginsplots together.